# Path to the website is causing trouble using the website name

Tags: regex, coldfusion, lucee

I have two websites:

```
website.com
dev.website.com
```

Both websites have different configurations based upon the above. I write a code to identify the dev and main website, but it is always picking up the dev, even if I am on the main website.

Here is the code:

```
<cfif ReFindNoCase("^(dev\.)?website\.com$",CGI.SERVER_NAME) NEQ 0>
```

Comment: Because the `?` equates to "match **zero** or more" instances of `dev.`". That's true in both cases. Get rid of the `?`

Comment: `<cfif ReFindNoCase("^(dev\.)website\.com$",CGI.SERVER_NAME) EQ 0>` will refer to dev - correct?

Comment: No. `0` means it's *not* dev.

Answer (score 3):

An easier, and less RegExy, way to handle this might be

```
<cfif listFirst( cgi.server_name, '.') NEQ 'dev' >
```

Comment: Well if you're going to use common sense ... ;-)

Comment: @Ageax I love RegEx, but, they are not always the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfset inDevelopment = (reFindNoCase("^dev\.website\.com$", CGI.SERVER_NAME) gt 0)>
<cfset inProduction  = (not inDevelopment)>
```

But you should prefer Scott's solution for simplicity, unless you really have to check the full hostname:

```
<cfset inDevelopment = (listFirst(CGI.SERVER_NAME, ".") eq "dev")>
<cfset inProduction  = (not inDevelopment)>
```

On a side note: If your domain is actually `dev.com`, the `listFirst`-solution will always put you in development. :D